# How to add one user to multiple calendars in Exchange using PowerShell

Tags: calendar, exchange-2013

Our company had many calendars, and often, we get a request asking for 1 user to be added to multiple calendars. These users need to have full delegated access. Is there a way to do this via PowerShell where it is not having to be done manually? Most of the time the user is needing to be added upto 10 calendars.